# Input type='text' value not fetched through id in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what's that. I'm trying to fetch text from input field through id, and the input field is within a while loop as there are multiple input fields. Here is my code:

```
if($count22->num_rows>0){               
    while($row = $count22->fetch_array()){      
        $mail = $row['UserMail'];
        $comment = $row['Comment'];
        $comment_id = $row['ID'];
        // Reply input field starts 
        echo " <input type='text' name='reply' id='reply' placeholder='Enter Reply here' min='5' max='100' class='big-input' style='width:40%;margin-left:40px;margin-right:40px;'>";

        echo "<button class='btn btn-outline-info' onclick='InsertReply($comment_id)'>Reply</button>";
    }        
}
```

On clicking button, InsertReply function is called where input field is checked whether it is empty or not.

InsertReply() function:

```
function InsertReply(x) {
    alert("Insert Reply Function Called! with comment id : " + x);
    //Storing values in variables
    var reply = document.getElementById("reply").value; //Error Here, not accepting reply
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var p_id = document.getElementById("postid").value;
    if (reply.length == 0) { //If user has entered nothing
        alert("You Entered Nothing!"); //Show message
    }
}
```

The issue is that it is fetching text from only first input field, it is showing alert box 'You entered nothing' for the rest of the input fields even if I enter text.
Let me know if you have any queries, any alternative solution/suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Comment: 1. There is no loop here. 2. You're not using the `x` parameter which is supposed to be the ID 3. Do you have multiple fields with the same ID? Because IDs should be unique.

Comment: I'm using x value later while sending ajax request. I have not mentioned that code as it was not required. If it is needed I can provide that

Comment: @VLAZ there is a `while` loop on the second line of the first code snippet

Comment: @nevada_scout not in the part that fetches values through ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to handle multiple input with the same `name`, you should add `[]` after their name in order to maintain them all when submitting the form.

Try this:

```
echo " <input type='text' name='reply[$comment_id]' id='reply_$comment_id' placeholder='Enter Reply here' min='5' max='100' class='big-input' style='width:40%;margin-left:40px;margin-right:40px;'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='mail[$comment_id]' id='mail_$comment_id' value= '".$current_user."'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='postid[$comment_id]' id='postid_$comment_id' value= '".$id."'/>";
```

In the PHP page that receive the form data, you'll get them as array, e.g.:

```
$_POST['reply'][here the comment id]
$_POST['mail'][here the comment id]
$_POST['postid'][here the comment id]
```

To know all the input data do `print_r($_POST)` (if the post has `method='get'` then use the `$_GET` variable instead.

Note also that I added the id for each `id` attribute because in the whole HTML  document all `id`s must be unique.

```
function InsertReply(x) {

    alert("Insert Reply Function Called! with comment id : " + x);
    //Storing values in variables
    var reply = document.getElementById("reply_" + x).value; //Error Here, not accepting reply
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail_" + x).value;
    var p_id = document.getElementById("postid_" + x).value;
    if (reply.length == 0) {      //If user has entered nothing
        alert("You Entered Nothing!");  //Show message
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to fetch these values in InsertReply Function?

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad you're wecome!